# What is the advantage of using Elixir's "with"

Tags: elixir

[I saw this code at the Elixir School](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/control-structures/#with):

```
with {:ok, user} <- Repo.insert(changeset),
     {:ok, token, full_claims} <- Guardian.encode_and_sign(user, :token, claims) do
  important_stuff(token, full_claims)
end
```

I don't get the difference to simply:

```
{:ok, user} <- Repo.insert(changeset),
{:ok, token, full_claims} <- Guardian.encode_and_sign(user, :token, claims)
important_stuff(token, full_claims)
```

Comment: First sentence of your link: "The special form `with/1` is useful when you might use a nested `case/2` statement or situations that cannot cleanly be piped together."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{:ok, user} <- Repo.insert(changeset)` without `with` would raise `(CompileError) undefined function <-/2` in the first place. You probably meant `{:ok, user} = Repo.insert(changeset)`.

**[`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1) plays the role of *Either monad* to some extent.**

If *RHO* matches to *LHO*, it goes to the next clause. Otherwise, it immediately early returns the non-matched *RHO*, discarding all the other clauses. Consider several functions that should be applied sequentially, if and nobly if the previous one succeeds. Somewhat along these lines.

```rb
with {:ok, text} <- File.read(name),
     {:ok, words} <- MyStemmer.get_words(text),
     count when in_integer(count) <- Enum.count(words),
  do: IO.puts("File contained #{count}" words)
```

If there is no such file, the whole snippet would return `{:error, :enoent}` because the very first clause would fail to pattern match *LHO*.

`{:ok, text} = File.read(name)` would instead raise `MatchError` when there is no such file.

---

I have written a [blog post](https://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2017/02/17/either-monad-in-elixir) on the subject three years ago, it might be still worth reading.